# Interception of routes with number of trips

Tags: r, r-sf

I have an sf data frame with the number of trips from one bike station to another. The geometry column contains the direct route (as given by osm) between the two sations.

I want to plot a map with the streets colored by a gradient of the number of trips that went on it.

My problem is that I have the number of trips by routes and not by streets.

I use `st_interception()` to extract the same part of two routes and `st_difference()` to extract the differences.

For two lines with 10 and 15 trips here is what I want.

```
library('sf')
library('ggplot2') # dev version

route1 <- st_linestring(rbind(c(0, 0), c(1, 1), c(2, 2), c(3, 3)))
route2 <- st_linestring(rbind(c(1, 0), c(1, 1), c(2, 2), c(3, 0)))

route1 <- st_sf(id = 1, trips = 10, geometry = st_sfc(route1))
route2 <- st_sf(id = 2, trips = 15, geometry = st_sfc(route2))

# not ok as the segment (1,1 to 2,2) that is supposed to have 25 trips   only has 15 (the number of trips for the second line plotted)
ggplot(data = rbind(route1, route2)) + geom_sf(mapping = aes(color = trips)) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'transparent'))

# mergeRoutes gives the desired output
route <- mergeRoutes(route1, route2, init = TRUE)
ggplot(data = route) + geom_sf(mapping = aes(color = trips)) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'transparent'))
```

I wrote the function mergeRoute, it gives what I want for two routes but it cannot be extended well for lots and lots of routes.

```
#'
#' This function merges two routes. It returns the interscetion (if any) with the number
#' of associated count and also the remaining pars of the routes or the second route or
#' (if init) the two routes.
#'
#' @param route1 a row with id , count and geometry
#' @param route2 a row with id , count and geometry
#' @param init logical, whether to return the two routes even if there is no intersection
#'   or only the second one
#'
#' @return a data frame with 3 rows if there is an intersection, nothing otherwise.
#'   
mergeRoutes <- function(route1, route2, init = FALSE) 
{
  intersection <- st_intersection(route1$geometry, route2$geometry)
  # if the intersection is only points or is empty then the result is the two routes
  # untouched to avoid adding too many elements to the result
  if(length(intersection) != 0 & 
     !'sfc_POINT' %in% class(intersection) &
     !'sfc_MULTIPOINT' %in% class(intersection)) {
    # if intersection is a geometry with point and lines extract the lines only
    intersection <- st_collection_extract(x = intersection, type = "LINESTRING")
    count <- route1$count + route2$count
    intersection <- data.frame(id = route1$id, count = count, geometry = intersection)
    # keep the part of the initial routes that are not in the intersection
    route1_dif <- st_difference(route1$geometry, route2$geometry)
    route2_dif <- st_difference(route2$geometry, route1$geometry)
    # if one route is completely covered by the the other then it is not added to the result
    if(length(route1_dif) != 0) {
      route1 <- data.frame(id = route1$id, 
                           count = route1$count, 
                           geometry = route1_dif)
    } else {
      route1 <- NULL
    }
    if(length(route2_dif) != 0) {
      route2 <- data.frame(id = route2$id, 
                           count = route2$count, 
                           geometry = route2_dif)
    } else {
      route2 <- NULL
    }
    result <- rbind(intersection, route1, route2)
    return(result)
  } else if (init) {
    result <- rbind(route1, route2)
  } else {
    result <- route2
  }
  return(result)
}
```

So I have something that works on two lines but if I try to loop over all the routes between all the stations, it goes undefinitely. I could not come with a better way than a `lapply()` inside a for loop and this does not terminate on my mac (16gb of ram, 2.5 ghz), it frozes at some point even after a 15h run.

Here is my attemp to work on almost 2000 routes (data can be found [here](https://github.com/MathieuMarauri/Maps/blob/master/directions.rds)).

```
# To merge all the routes, each new route is compared to all the rows from the previous
# comparison. New rows are added to the resulting data frame at each step. If there is no
# intersection then the route being compared to the others is added untouched.

# initiate comparison
segment_routes <- mergeRoutes(route1 = directions %>% slice(1), 
                              route2 = directions %>% slice(2), 
                              init = TRUE)

# compute directions segmentation for all the routes
for(i in 3:nrow(directions)) {
  new_route <- directions %>% slice(i)
  # compare the new route to a the segments resulting fro mprevious comparison
  new_routes <- lapply(X = seq(nrow(segment_routes)), 
                       FUN = function(j) mergeRoutes(route1 = segment_routes %>% slice(j), 
                                                     route2 = new_route))
  new_routes <- do.call(rbind, new_routes)
  # make an sf object
  new_routes <- st_sf(new_routes, 
                      geometry = new_routes$geometry, 
                      crs = st_crs(directions))
  # add the new segemnts to the ones from the previous iteration
  segment_routes <- rbind(segment_routes, new_routes)
}
```

I know you can pass a data frame directly to `st_intersection()` but I do not know how to specify that I want the count to be added and besides more than 2 routes can share the same part of a street so a single call to interception will not provide the correct output.

I use `sf` and data frames here but any solution using `sp` and/or `data.table` or another package would be perfect for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: here is my session info

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 sf_0.6-0          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15      class_7.3-14      withr_2.1.1.9000  plyr_1.8.4       
 [5] grid_3.4.3        gtable_0.2.0      DBI_0.7           magrittr_1.5     
 [9] e1071_1.6-8       units_0.5-1       scales_0.5.0.9000 pillar_1.2.1     
[13] rlang_0.2.0       lazyeval_0.2.1    tools_3.4.3       udunits2_0.13    
[17] munsell_0.4.3     yaml_2.1.17       compiler_3.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 
[21] classInt_0.1-24   tibble_1.4.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Methodology

Under the assumption that all your routes will be `LINESTRINGS`, and that a `LINESTRING` is simply a sequence of coordiantes, we can treat each sequential coordinate pair as a 'from' and a 'to'.

If we use `data.table` to store the coordinates (rather than `sf`), the solution becomes a simple grouping & counting operation, and should scale well to a larger data set.

#### Example

Here's an example on the data you've provided in the link

**Step 1** - convert to `data.table`

```
library(sf)
library(data.table)
library(googleway) ## for plotting. can also use ggplot2, ggmap, leaflet, mapview...

sf <- readRDS("~/Downloads/directions.rds")
sf$row_id <- 1:nrow(sf) ## for joining 

dt_routes <- as.data.table(st_coordinates(sf))

## put on the rest of the trip data
## this assumes the 'L1' value from `st_coordinates` matches the 
## `id` value from the sf_routes object
## (if not, you will need a sequential 1:nrow 'id' value to match the 
## 'L1' value)
dt_sf <- sf
st_geometry(dt_sf) <- NULL

dt_routes <- dt_routes[
  dt_sf
    , on = c(L1 = "row_id")
    , nomatch = 0
  ]
```

**Step 2** - create 'from' and 'to'

We can shift the X and Y columns to give us 'from' and 'to' columns

```
dt_routes[
    , `:=`(X_to = shift(X, type = "lead"),
           Y_to = shift(Y, type = "lead"))
    , by = L1
  ]
```

**Step 3** - Group & Count

Now we can calculate the number of trips per each coordinate pair

```
dt_trips <- dt_routes[
    !is.na(X_to)
    , .(n_trips = sum(count))
    , by = .(X, Y, X_to, Y_to)
  ]
```

**Step 4** - Convert back to `sf`

After a bit of rearranging we can now convert each from/to pair to `LINESTRINGS`, each with their own weight (i.e., `num_trips`)

```
dt_trips[, line_id := .I]

dt_from <- dt_trips[, .(X, Y, n_trips, line_id)]
dt_to <- dt_trips[, .(X = X_to, Y = Y_to, n_trips, line_id)]

dt_from[, line_sequence := 1]
dt_to[, line_sequence := 2]

dt_trips <- rbindlist(list(
  dt_from, dt_to
))

setorder(dt_trips, line_id, line_sequence)

## convert back to `sf` object
dt_trips <- dt_trips[, {
  geometry <- sf::st_linestring(x = matrix(c(X, Y), ncol = 2))
  geometry <- sf::st_sfc(geometry)
  geometry <- sf::st_sf(geometry)
}, by = .(line_id, n_trips)]

sf_trips <- sf::st_as_sf(dt_trips)
```

**Step 5** - Plot

```
## applying a log-transform so the contrast shows up
sf_trips$n_trips <- log(sf_trips$n_trips)

library(googleway)
set_key("GOOGLE_MAP_KEY")

google_map(data = sf_trips) %>%
  add_polylines(
    stroke_colour = "n_trips"
    , stroke_opacity =1
    , stroke_weight = 3.5
    #, legend = T
    , info_window = "n_trips"
    , palette = viridisLite::viridis
  )
```

[image]